# Understanding character array in C

Tags: c

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

int check_pal(char *s)
{
    int l = strlen(s),mid,i,h1[256]={0},h2[256]={0};
    mid = l/2;
    if(l&1)
        for(i=0;i<mid;i++)
        {
            //printf("%c %c\n",s[i],s[i+mid]);
            h1[s[i]]++;
            h2[s[i+mid+1]]++;
        }
    else
        for(i=0;i<mid;i++)
        {
            //printf("%c %c\n",s[i],s[i+mid]);
            h1[s[i]]++;
            h2[s[i+mid]]++;
        }

    for(i=0;i<256;i++)
        if(h1[i]!=h2[i])
            return 0;
    return 1;
}

int main()
{
    int t;
    char s[1001];
    scanf("%d",&t);
    while(t--)
    {
        scanf("%s",s);
        if(check_pal(s))
            printf("YES\n");
        else
            printf("NO\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

In the above program I want to understand the step `h1[s[i]]++;` and
`h2[s[i+mid]]++;`

Comment: `h1` and `h2` are histograms, where each bin is a single character.

Answer (score 2):

This function is checking that the frequencies of characters are the same in the first half and second half of the string.

Take `h1[s[i]]++;`

`s[i]` is character `i` of string `s`. `h1[]` is the number of characters seen in the first half. `h1[s[i]]` is the number for the given character. The `++` increments the count for that character.

`h2[s[i+mid]]++;` Is the same for the second half of the string. The `+mid` means we are looking at the second half of the string.

Then it checks the frequencies match for all characters.

Answer (score 1):

`h1[s[i]]++` uses the contents of s[i] to index into the h1 array, and then increments the value in that location of the h1 array.

Similarly, `h2[s[i+mid]]++` Uses the contents of s[i+mid] to index into the h2 array, and then increments the value in that location of the h2 array.

Comment: thanks but i want to know ,what will be the value of h1[s[0]].

Comment: you should probably change the question to state that then - you asked "In the above program I want to understand the step h1[s[i]]++; and h2[s[i+mid]]++;"